# SQLite database accessible by multiple users/mobile devices

Tags: sqlite

I am creating an app for auction, where it requires multiple access to the sqlite database from different mobile devices. However, I found out that each device will have its own database, a standalone one. I am trying to allow every device to share the same database. I googled online and it's actually possible but I don't see any examples. Does any of you have tried using sqlite for for access by multiple users, do you mind sharing? I know mysql can do the job or other serve based database, but I only got time to continue using sqlite.

Comment: Does "device" refer to something mobile?

Comment: Yup.such as mobile phones etc.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is not designed for access over a network, and while you *could* use something like *Windows File & Print Sharing* to allow multiple devices to access it, I'd be surprised if that didn't result in data corruption due to multiple writes from different sources.

There is no good solution to your problem that doesn't involve the applications *not* accessing a SQLite database directly.

Generally, if you want multiple applications to access a database over a network, you would put a web service in front of the database and have the applications talk to the web service over HTTPS.

Comment: So are you saying I can keep sqlite and just add a web server to it?or I have to change my database as well to mysql etc?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is file-based. While it is possible (but often [dangerous](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html)) to access a database on a network file system, mobile OSes like Android or iOS do not have network file systems, and do not allow direct access to files on other computers.

You have to put the database on a server, and write an interface (some web service) through which the mobile apps can access it. (For the apps and for the interface, it does not matter which database the server uses; using SQLite there [is possible](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html), too.)